# Why do I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS Error when deleting values from a UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, exc-bad-access

I am creating an app where I have data stored in a UITableView inside a view controlled by a class I have created, `TeamsViewController`. I have code to delete values from the table, but sometimes (not always), the app will crash  when you delete values from the table view.

I get the error `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)` on the class declaration of my AppDelegate:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate
```

Here is the code for `TeamsViewController`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!
var data: [Team]()

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if(table != nil)
    {
        self.table.delegate = self
        self.table.dataSource = self
        self.table.reloadData()
    }
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!)
{
    println("1234")
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete)
    {
        data.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        table.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Note that `Team` is a class that I have created .

I have omitted some of the tableView code, tell me if it is needed and I will add it.

Some more information that might be helpful is that "1234" is NOT printed to the console when the app crashes.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What line is it crashing on? You need to include that method.

Comment: Where's your cellForRowAtIndexPath? Also commitEditingStyle should have an override in front of it.

Comment: The cellForRowAtIndexPath method is part of the code I omitted because I thought it was irrelevant.

Comment: It isn't irrelevant, that's probably where the crash occurred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not certain what error it is, but based on a tutorial I did on tableViews, their swipe-to-delete function override contained this line:

`tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: .Automatic)`

Maybe adding that line would clear your error.

Comment: This solved the problem. I also didn't need the line table.reloadData() anymore.

Comment: Don't think this would solve your problem. This is essentially the same as reloadData() except it just reloads the specific rows, such as if you wanted to animate the deletion.

Comment: @shim It did stop the crash. It may just be a bug with UITableView or something.

Comment: That's pretty unlikely, you probably fixed it elsewhere somehow.